# Trouble with splitting a string in python and then comparing each individual section to a list of values

Tags: python, string

I'm having trouble with a lab. I'm tasked with taking in input, splitting that input based on spaces, and testing to see if its in a separate list. I have a function that sees if the value is in the list but when I test a phrase that I know is in the list, nothing shows up. I tried to see how the string split was splitting my phrase "austin is cool" and when I inputted city[0], it returned just an "a". I also created functions that parsed through a txt file and created a list so I could compare and another one that actually checked to see if the word was located in the list. Below is my final program + functions:

```
def load_city_corpus():
    city_list = []
    filename = "NYC2-cities.txt"
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            city_list.append(line.strip())
    return city_list
```

\\\\\

```
def is_a_city(city,city_list):
    try:
        index = city_list.index(city)
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

\\\\\

```
list_of_cities = load_city_corpus
while True:
   city_test = input("Enter some text (or ENTER to quit):")
   if city_test == "":
      break
   city_test.split(" ")
   print(city_test[0]) #prints "a"
   for item in city_test:
      if is_a_city(city_test,list_of_cities) == True:
          print(f"{city_test.title()} is a city")
   else:
      break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few errors in your code.  Here's a fixed version with some comments:

```
def load_city_corpus():
    city_list = []
    filename = "NYC2-cities.txt"
    # return ['austin', 'boston'] # my stub for testing...
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            city_list.append(line.strip()) # could add lower() for safety...
    return city_list

def is_a_city(city, city_list):
    try:
        index = city_list.index(city) # could be city.lower() for safety
        return True
    except ValueError: # AttributeError:
        return False

list_of_cities = load_city_corpus() # Need the () to call the func
while True:
   city_test = input("Enter some text (or ENTER to quit): ")
   if city_test == "":
      break
   city_test = city_test.split() # (" ") not an error to use, but not nec.
   # ^^^^^^^^^^ have to assign the result of the split to preserve it...
   print(city_test[0]) #prints "a" -- not anymore! :)
   for item in city_test:
      if is_a_city(item, list_of_cities) == True: # item, not city_test
          print(f"{item.title()} is a city")          # item, not city_test
   # get rid of the below, because it will always break out of the loop after one pass.
   # else:
   #    break
```

Reading through your post again, I notice that you use "austin is cool" as if it were entered as input. So, are you trying to check if the first word of the input is a city, or if any word of the input is a city? The above code handles the latter.

Also, don't hesitate to use an additional variable to hold the `city_test.split()` results.  Doing so can make the code easier to read, follow, and debug.  You just have to make sure to use that new variable in all the proper places. So...

```
city_splits = city_test.split()
print(city_splits[0]) #prints "a" -- not anymore! :)
for item in city_splits:
   if is_a_city(item, list_of_cities) == True: # item, not city_test
       print(f"{item.title()} is a city")          # item, not city_test
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This definitely helps! Yeah, I meant to parse through the string to detect the city anywhere throughout the string, I just used "Austin is cool" as a way to test it. Again, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the result of your split - it doesn't happen in place. When you check `city_test[0]` you're simply checking the 0th element of your string - which is an A.

Replace `city_test.split(" ")` with `city_test = city_test.split(" ")` to make the functionality match your expectation.

Comment: Worth noting that there's a few other bugs in that code, so you might like to give it another read through!

Answer (score 0):

On using city_test.split(" "), you can split the string based on spaces. But the original city_test = ["austin is cool"] remains the same. Store the list in a variable after splitting.

> list_name = city_test.split(" ")

You can use another variable name instead of city_test and store it if you want the original list to be present.